# How to redirect tablet android to desktop web site version?

Tags: android, redirect, tablet

I've use a script to redirect mobile users to mobile site version, but I want to redirect the tablet users in desktop version.
The script is the following:

```
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
 location.replace("http://www.ilsanlorenzo.net/mobsite");
 }
 else if (screen.width <= 599) {
 document.location = "http://www.ilsanlorenzo.net/mobsite";
 }
 else if ( (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1) ) {
 document.location = "http://www.ilsanlorenzo.net/mobsite";
 }
else if ( (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('webos') != -1) ) {
 document.location = "http://www.ilsanlorenzo.net/mobsite";
 }
else if ( (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('symbian') != -1) ) {
 document.location = "http://www.ilsanlorenzo.net/mobsite";
 }
else if ( (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('blackberry') != -1) ) {
 document.location = "http://www.ilsanlorenzo.net/mobsite";
 }
else if ( (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('winphone') != -1) ) {
 document.location = "http://www.ilsanlorenzo.net/mobsite";
 }
```

Comment: Unrelated: You could use a switch-case statement instead to get rid of those duplicate rows (readability).

Comment: What about this? <meta name="viewport"

Comment: Can you give me a example?